# C# How to receive a Message from Service Bus Queue and Deadletterqueue with Sequence Number

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I want to create my own Monitoring Tool for an Service Bus Queue. To Delete an specific Message in the normal Queue and Deadletterqueue, I need to receive a Message by a Sequence Number. But I can't find a such Method in my Receiver Object. I see a Method to Peek Messages with a Sequence Number, but i can't Complete them and its also not possible on Deatletter Messages. Is there a such Method to get Messages by Sequence Number?

Answer (score 0):

Not supported and only might be considered for dead-letter queues. See this broker feature [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/453) for discussion.